# MediaWiki:Sitenotice coding

Tags: mediawiki

I am trying to duplicate the site notice banner that is displayed on the top of Wikipedia.Org on my own mediawiki site, but the source is protected and not visible to regular users (so it appears anyway).  Does anyone know how to duplicate this kind of thing?  I am already familiar with the MediaWiki:Sitenotice page that needs to be editted, but the one on Wikipedia has CSS included and HTML elements that I don't believe is possible to duplicate in Wikitext.  Anyone familiar with the method used to create this kind of banner?

Just goto http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page and I am referring to the "Please read a personal message" banner at the top.  You can see the "protected" source here: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=MediaWiki:Sitenotice&action=edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm, looks like they are using CentralNotice rather than Sitenotice.

http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:CentralNotice